# Can't input specific keys RK61

Tags: keyboard-layout

I got a problem with the RK61 keyboard, a 60% keyboard in German layout.
Now there is the problem that some keys like the special characters won't work, some being:
@ { } [] ³²~|.
I also have to mention that I operate Ubuntu through a virtual machine in windows, if that has to be considered.

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu?  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting